# Python 3: CSV utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to write a CSV with non-ascii character using Python 3.

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow("嗨")
```

When I open the Excel file, see `å—¨` instead. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could the issue be with Excel not recognizing the encoding? Can you try following these instructions: https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to indicate to Excel that this is a UTF-8 file; it won't assume so automatically.

You do this by putting a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write('\ufeff')
```

Comment: If I don't want to write to a file, but I want to write to a buffer, how should I do it? Can you show example?

Comment: @user1187968 since your question didn't show writing to a buffer, I'm unsure how you would use `csv` to do that.

Comment: There is also `encoding='utf_8_sig'`, which inserts the BOM automatically. This is nice from a programmer's point of view, but maybe less so for an encoding purist (because UTF-8 doesn't actually need the BOM like UTF-16 does).